# Changing multidimensional array of bytes to method for multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

Here's some code I've been playing around with, I was wondering how i'd change the code so it'd do the same but for an `ArrayList<byte[]>`

```
 private static void transposeba(byte[][] m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                byte x = m[i][j];
                m[i][j] = m[j][i];
                m[j][i] = x;
            }
        }
    }
```

such:

```
 private static void transposeba(ArrayList<byte[]> m)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an `ArrayList<byte>`.  Do you mean `ArrayList<Byte>` or `ArrayList<byte[]>` or `ArrayList<List<Byte>>`?

Comment: yes sorry @LouisWasserman check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static void transposeba(List<byte[]> m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < m.get(0).length; j++) {
            byte x = m.get(i)[j];
            m.get(i)[j] = m.get(j)[i];
            m.get(j)[i] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about something like m[i] = m[k] how would i write that as arraylist?

Comment: `m.set(i, m.get(k))`, naturally.